# rails radio buttons choose available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have radio buttons, i want if i choose first variant my `<%= f.text_field :price %>` is be available, and if i choose second variant `<%= f.text_field :price %>` is not be available

```
<%= f.radio_button :price, true %><%= f.label :price %>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
    <%= f.radio_button :price, false %><%= f.label :price %>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:price, "price") %>
```

how can you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good dude advised use this script:

```
<%= f.radio_button :price, false %><%= f.label :price %>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
    <%= f.radio_button :price, true %><%= f.label :price %>
    <script>$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#post_price_true').change(function(){
        $('#post_price').attr('disabled','disabled');
      });
      $('#post_price_false').change(function(){
        $('#post_price').removeAttr('disabled');
      });
      });</script>
```

odin nol' v pol'zu zritelei